# Using Were vs. Was with Proper Nouns

Tags: proper-nouns

My first language is not English and I have a question about a sentence that I recently saw. And I hope someone can help me.

Is it correct to say:

"I wish John were a myth so you could bust him."

instead of:

"I wish John was a myth so you could bust him."

And if both are correct, what are the difference between the two?

Comment: Trying reading up on the difference in *was* and *were*, as well as what types of nouns they are used with. http://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference

Comment: The sentence *might* be formed with the television show called "Mythbusters" in mind. If you are not familiar with the program, this sentence would be even more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the proper noun is important to the distinction here, which is between the indicative and subjunctive mode. As used here, *was* is indicative, while *were* is subjunctive and the better word to follow "I wish."  This would still be the case if some common noun were involved instead of *John*. "I wish my wife were here," not "I wish my wife was here." But I suppose that many native speakers ignore this distinction and *was* is common in this context.